# Dart: how to get the current index of a list element in a client side Polymer element?

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer

I'm pretty new to Dart and was trying to know how to get the current index of an element in a list in the case as described below:

1) I run a server when a list of objects is fetched from a database and sent to the client side Dart web app via JSON
2) On the Dart client side web page I want to layout the elements of that list in a table but in a mod3 fashion, i.e. over N rows per three columns.

So I though to scan the list using the Polymer template, fetch the current element, add it to the table (i.e. write an HTML tag), then check if the index of the current element  mod3 (%3) 
is = to zero.

My problem is that I don't know how to fetch that list current element index

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to access the index of the current iterator being used in your polymer repeat statement, is to use the enumerate filter.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <table>
      <tbody template repeat="{{item in myList | enumerate}}">
        <template if="{{item.index % 3 == 0}}">
          <tr>
        </template>
      <td>item.value</td>
        <template if="{{item.index % 3 == 0}}">
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

However this is not totally completed as there were issues in the past in which you could not use a `<template>` within a table element. I'm not 100% sure if that is still the case or not (as I have been unable to locate any definitive information stating resolution or not). An alternative is to use `<div>`'s and classes to layout your data.

Simply use some CSS to set the div's style to `table`, `table-row`, or `table-cell` respectively. See [CSS Display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) on W3Schools for more information. The `<div>` solution would permit templates as required.